# Построение изображения из массива, для получения карты высот

Tags: c#

С#.
Алгоритм "Diamond-Square" генерирует массив `double[x, y]`. Подскажите, как получить изображение карты высот из массива высот? Что бы получилось что то в этом роде:

[image: Карта высот]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Вас есть размеры изображения (размеры массива) и для каждой координаты точки (индексы массива) есть число, которое можно привести к цвету пикселя.

Создаем битмап нужного размера. 
Получаем для каждого пикселя нужный цвет (ну, скажем через `Color.FromArgb()`). Через `Bitmap.SetPixel()` устанавливаем этот цвет.

Comment: Благодарю за комментарий. Все получилось. Спасибо!